# PS-Remote shell access to a user

Tags: powershell, powershell-v3.0, powershell-v4.0, powershell-v5.0

I am currently adding Full control to an user manually. Please see below screen shot.
But this needs to be done via a PS script.I followed https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/11/18/use-powershell-to-set-security-permissions-for-remoting/ link but I am getting an error while executing this one by one. Please suggest.

Error-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $user = "bsg\sisyphus"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $accval = New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount $user
PS C:\Windows\system32> $accval

Value
-----
bsg\sisyphus


PS C:\Windows\system32> $sid = $accval.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At line:1 char:1
+ $sid = $accval.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Val ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKgJO.png)

Comment: Are you sure the user name is correct?  You can make sure everything is otherwise correct with `(New-Object Security.Principal.NTAccount (whoami)).Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])`

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming Security.Principal.NTAccount to System.Security.Principal.NTAccount and see if you get a different error.